# Как сделать свою библиотеку подключаемой через зависимости gradle

Tags: java, android, github, gradle

На github часто можно встретить такой код для `build.gradle` файла -

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.lusfold.spinnerloading:spinnerloading:1.0.0'
}
```

Если добавить эту зависимость в проект, то подключаемая библиотека компилируется автоматически, что очень упрощает процесс её подключения.

Такой вопрос - если я сам создал какую-нибудь библиотеку и выложил её на github, как мне сгенерировать такую же ссылку, чтобы люди (и я, при необходимости повторного использования) могли так же просто подключать мою библиотеку в свои проекты?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во первых подключаемая библиотека не компилируется, она скачивается с maven репозитория уже скомпилированная.

Ну а что бы пользователи смогли пользоваться вашей библиотекой подключая её похожим образом нужно выложить её в публично доступный репозиторий. Как это сделать хорошо описано в [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/266801/). Там правда немного избыточно, для публикации библиотеки в jCenter шаги 2 и 3 не нужны, они нужны для публикации ещё и в Maven Central.

Есть ещё совсем простой способ именно для GitHub: [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/). Но с ним пользователю придётся добавить, кроме непосредственно строки описывающей зависимость от Вашей библиотеки, ещё и ссылку на репозиторий. В общем у них на сайте всё подробно расписано.